# Beeing root but without knowing password. Replacing binaries in /bin/ to bypass restrictions

Tags: password, root, binary, passwd

I have an active root account, but I don't know my password.

To be able to change my password or even to create another users (with the tool `passwd`) I need to know my password. So that creates a problem. But since I'm root - am I allowed to replace arbitrary binaries in `/bin/` directory? Just modify `passwd` source code, compile it, replace the original one with the new one. Is it that simple? Any caveats?

My test systems are: `FreeBSD 11.0` + `Ubuntu 18.04`

Comment: Why can't you just set a new password for root?

Comment: What OS? (Linux? Some BSD?)

Comment: Is it that simple? But i need to know old password in order to change my password? I heard that it was possible to create users without any passwords. Is it still allowed on modern unix/linux systems?

Comment: root can change passwords without knowing the old password.

Comment: You cannot create new users using `passwd`. But yes, if you have root privileges you can replace any binary on the system with anything you wish.

Comment: after using unix/linux over so many years I never noticed that is so easy to change password if you opened a console as root. because i always wiped my OS usually after a year of usage and moved to another one. hence never run in such use case.

Answer (score 5):

Most Linuxes I've seen are configured so that `passwd` doesn't ask `root` for the old password:

```
root@xxx ~# passwd root
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
```

Even if `passwd` does ask for it, you could try `chpasswd`, or edit `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` by hand (the password hash is the second field, the long blurb of characters between two colons) It's just that you'd need to compute the hash first, `openssl` is just one of the tools to do that:

```
$ echo foobar | openssl passwd -1 -stdin
$1$G/nr44th$wn16q7ITSvfrNq4amDfzn1
```

(You probably shouldn't really use the `MD5`-based `$1$` hash, but it doesn't matter since at least after resetting the hash to a known value, you could use `passwd` to change it.)

Comment: I read somewhere that one just can edit entries in /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow. Would it cause any problems? Is there any benefit from using passwd tool instead of doing it by hand? - I'm worrying about system stability and less about user friendliness which offers passwd tool.

Comment: @Awaaaaarghhh, you can edit `passwd` and `shadow` by hand. Or rather with `vipw`/`vipw -s`. You probably shouldn't do that on important systems, since well, there's always the chance of a typo leaving it impossible to log in. It probably helps to keep a root session open and test logging in before closing it. Actually you

Comment: Because my question was so heavily downvoted (I guess I asked a really stupid question) I would like to delete it. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @Awaaaaarghhh, I'm not sure how it works. It doesn't let you delete it because of an upvoted answer?

Comment: "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into *downvoting* it. For more information ...". never again.

Comment: @Awaaaaarghhh, I'm not sure what I can do about downvotes on your question.

Comment: It is not a stupid question, but it is not asked well. It is not clear what you are asking: are you asking “How do I regain access to my system?”, “I have access, but don't know the password. How do I change my password? And this is what I have tried.”, “I am curious about what can root do. Can root change anything on the system?”. If the question was clear, then I would have up-voted. As for deleting: I think you can vote to close, then when closed, you can vote to delete (I am not an expert in this area).